# Why is this transaction showing value as 0?

Tags: aave, private-transaction

New to crypto.

I see in the erc20 tokens column that there are some SNX tokens.
SNX was converted to aSNX then it was supposedly transferred to another wallet. But when I check that wallet there is no history of aSNX being sent. It shows 0??

Why is that? Am I missing something

https://etherscan.io/address/0x999e270b788c8f5dacb1e129bfd429789366871f#tokentxns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aSNX token was transferred to [this wallet](https://etherscan.io/address/0x4965d95ed2109e655e30d7f51dbc228b8dac3c66) with [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1ba57289b9a0fc90fc4f944c17be28a3404ab3d1b92b36eadbd3cd20c0191d98).

The aSNX tokens were redeemed and swapped a couple of days later with this [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4d6e133f916e1a1b81da0bf07f41a55387e4558c29f32b4074eb2b7ec35d4435).